# Is there a way to apply directive to nested anchor tags? Angular

Tags: angular

I want to apply directive to all anchor tags that are children of DIV element. how to restrict the influence of directive to apply only child elements.

Comment: isn't it possible to apply the directive to all the anchors explicitly like `<a directiveSelector href="...">` ?

Comment: no in my case it is imposible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules) for that. An anchor directive could be declared within a feature module alongside the `DIV` component.

Briefly, the strategy is:

1. Declare a feature module
2. Declare the `anchor` directive within the feature module, but don't export it
3. Declare (and export) the `DIV` component within the feature module. The `anchor` directive will be applied to all anchors within the `DIV` component
4. Import the feature module to the `AppModule`

The declaration of feature module will look like

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [TheDivComponent, AnchorDierctive],
  exports: [TheDivComponent]
})
export class TheDivModule {}
```